# Mongoose findOneAndUpdate with Schema _id set to false

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Typically, I would search / find the document. If a document is found, then I would update it... if not found then I would create it.

I'm Looking for a more efficient way to do this, from reading the docs - I've cobbled together the following (I'm also using hapi.js)

```
    const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

    let ProductSchema = new Schema({
        sku: String,
        active: Boolean,
        category: String,
        description: String,
        freeShipping: Boolean
    });
```

.... ProductSchema is exported, and required as 'Products'.. its used to create a new product. I pass in my payload (already validated through Joi).

```
     let product = new Products(request.payload);

        Products.findOneAndUpdate(
            { sku : request.payload.sku }, 
            {$set: product },
            { upsert: true,  new: true, runValidators: true },
            function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                return reply(Boom.badRequest('Error saving product'));
            }

            return reply(result); 

        });
```

- upsert: true - says create if not found.
- new: true - returns the    newly created or updated document (the
  result)
- runValidators: true -    should force the data (the product) to be validated against the schema.

However, I hit a problem with instantiating the product - Mongoose automatically inserts an "_id".

"_ids" are immutable. So when I try to update, I get the following error:

```
{ MongoError: After applying the update to the document {_id: ObjectId('59cc33812e36f3d0272dc28e') , ...}, the (immutable) field '_id' was found to have been altered to _id: ObjectId('59cc3c21e0938d99c2716989')
```

So, my first thought was - create the object using literal notation... I then have control to omit the "_id"...

However, doing this meant that the object was not created / validated by the schema...

I then read that you can suppress the creation an _id, by setting _id to false in your schema. I did this, and now get an object thats validated without an _id. Updating / creating now works without throwing errors.

Suppressing the "_id" field in my schema doesn't seem like much of an issue, as the Mongo server will always create a new _id for every entry. I'm using the SKU as my unique key.

However, I'm mindful that I arrived here through poking around and trying to figure things out.

So the nub of my question is - is my approach flawed?